# Vertical paper-slider element

Tags: html, polymer, paper-elements

I like the Polymer paper elements and I want to use a paper-slider element.

However, i would like it to be vertical. I've tried to apply css to rotate it;

`transform: rotate(90deg);`

This rotates the slider, but not the "input"; one must still click and drag the mouse **horizontally** in order to get the "knob" to move up and down.

This is very annoying and any help is rely appreciated!

Comment: The best way to get this addressed would be to open a feature request at https://github.com/Polymer/paper-slider/issues That being said, the logic for updating the knob due to user interaction is at https://github.com/Polymer/paper-slider/blob/master/paper-slider.html#L256 It's all based on coordinates in the X axis and the element's width. If you were ambitious, you could try forking the element and modifying that logic to all be based on the Y axis and the element's height.

Comment: Jenn Posnick, this is a great suggestion. I will start a request. But i think "If you were ambitious" is not enough, I'm sure a certain level of skill is required, I have looked at the source and found the x axis, but that was as far as I came...

Answer (score 0):

[tk-vslider](https://github.com/arunhedcet/tk-vslider) is a tweaked paper-slider with rotate functionality. Use this instead of paper-slider to solve this issue. Install using bower `"tkvslider": "0.5.5"`

```
<tk-vslider rotate="true"></tk-vslider>
```

Tweaks.

if `rotate == true` then

1. `div#sliderContainer` is css rotated by 90deg
2. Event `on-trackx` of the `div#sliderKnob` is replaced by `on-track`
3. In the method `track`take `e.dy` instead of `e.dx`.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a pretty hacky way to do it, but we're coming up a year since you [requested this as feature](https://github.com/Polymer/paper-slider/issues/25) and it doesn't look like it's much of a priority yet. I figure this will (for the most part) allow for continued updates of `paper-slider` from the Polymer team without depending on third parties that might not continue support (from what I can tell, the custom element `tk-vslider` mentioned here hasn't been updated to support Polymer 1.0).

First, the css. I found that if I rotated 90 degrees, the smaller values were at the top of the slider, which I found to be counter-intuitive. So instead I rotate by -90. Some weird stuff happens with the margins but this is what finally did it for me:

```
paper-slider {
    width: 20vh;
    margin: 10vh -10vh;
    --webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
   transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
```

I had my paper-slider inside my own custom element, so I put the following code in the ready callback, but I imagine you could put it anywhere you needed, as long as you can select the slider element. We're basically just going to override the method that `paper-slider` uses to respond to drag events. Here's how:

```
var slider = this.$.slider;
slider._trackX = function(e) {

  if (!slider.dragging) {
    slider._trackStart(e);
  }

  var dx = Math.min(slider._maxx, Math.max(slider._minx, (-1 * e.detail.dy)));
  slider._x = slider._startx + dx;

  var immediateValue = slider._calcStep(slider._calcKnobPosition(slider._x / slider._w));
  slider._setImmediateValue(immediateValue);

  // update knob's position
  var translateY = ((slider._calcRatio(immediateValue) * slider._w) - slider._startx);
  slider.translate3d(translateY + 'px', 0, 0, slider.$.sliderKnob);
};
```

Almost the entirety of this method is copied over from `paper-slider` [source code](https://github.com/PolymerElements/paper-slider/blob/master/paper-slider.html), the only real change is that instead of grabbing the x coordinate in `e.detail.dx` we grab the y in `e.detail.dy`. The negative multiplier is only necessary if you want smaller values at the bottom of your slider, and you rotated your `paper-slider` by -90 degrees. **Note that if the Polymer team ever changes the name of the method `_trackX`, it'll break this solution.** I know this is a bit late but hopefully it'll help anyone else finding themselves in a similar situation (as I did).

UPDATE: Probably should have tested this solution a bit more, turns out there's another function that needs to be overwritten to handle click events (the other one only handles drag). I got it to work by adding this below my other method:

```
slider._bardown = function(event) {
  slider._w = slider.$.sliderBar.offsetWidth;
  var rect = slider.$.sliderBar.getBoundingClientRect();
  var ratio = ((rect.bottom - event.detail.y) / slider._w);
  var prevRatio = slider.ratio;

  slider._setTransiting(true);

  slider._positionKnob(ratio);

  slider.debounce('expandKnob', slider._expandKnob, 60);

  // if the ratio doesn't change, sliderKnob's animation won't start
  // and `_knobTransitionEnd` won't be called
  // Therefore, we need to manually update the `transiting` state

  if (prevRatio === slider.ratio) {
    slider._setTransiting(false);
  }

  slider.async(function() {
    slider.fire('change');
  });

  // cancel selection
  event.preventDefault();
}
```

The main change to this method is the line that calculates the ratio. Before it was `var ratio = (event.detail.x - rect.left) / this._w;`

Answer (score 0):

`<s-slider>` has `vertical` property for vertical orientation https://github.com/StartPolymer/s-slider

Answer (score 0):

zberry's answer didnt work for me anymore. However, I took his answer and updated it. The Polymer3 solution to make the paper-slider vertically responsive would look like this (given the same CSS zberry used):

```
let slider = this.shadowRoot.querySelector('paper-slider');
slider._trackX = function(event) {
  if (!slider.dragging) {
    slider._trackStart(event);
  }
  var dx =
      Math.min(slider._maxx, Math.max(slider._minx, -1 * event.detail.dy));
      slider._x = slider._startx + dx;
  var immediateValue =
      slider._calcStep(slider._calcKnobPosition(slider._x / slider._w * 100));
      slider._setImmediateValue(immediateValue);
  // update knob's position
  var translateX =
      ((slider._calcRatio(slider.immediateValue) * slider._w) - 
slider._knobstartx);
  slider.translate3d(translateX + 'px', 0, 0, slider.$.sliderKnob);
};

slider._barclick = function(event) {
  slider._w = slider.$.sliderBar.offsetWidth;
  var rect = slider.$.sliderBar.getBoundingClientRect();
  var ratio = (rect.bottom - event.detail.y) / slider._w * 100;
  if (slider._isRTL) {
    ratio = 100 - ratio;
  }
  var prevRatio = slider.ratio;
  slider._setTransiting(true);
  slider._positionKnob(ratio);
  // if the ratio doesn't change, sliderKnob's animation won't start
  // and `_knobTransitionEnd` won't be called
  // Therefore, we need to manually update the `transiting` state
  if (prevRatio === slider.ratio) {
    slider._setTransiting(false);
  }
  slider.async(function() {
    slider.fire('change', {composed: true});
  });
  // cancel selection
  event.preventDefault();
  // set the focus manually because we will called prevent default
  slider.focus();
};
```

If you want to slide from top to down you have to fiddle with the directions